# Disabling the mouse scrollwheel in PowerPoint

Tags: mouse, microsoft-powerpoint

I love the scrollwheel on my mouse, but I want to tell PowerPoint to ignore it. Is there
a way to do this without turning it off completely?

If I'm demoing something, I need it on when I'm in the demo, but I want it off when I'm in the slide deck. I don't want to accidentally touch the thing and have it scroll too many slides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, if you have a microsoft mouse, you can install their [IntelliPoint](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/download/download.aspx?category=mk) software, which allows you to customize what the mouse buttons do in various applications. You could disable the scroll wheel completely in PowerPoint, but leave it enabled elsewhere.

Comment: I'll check this option out, and hit accept if it works.

Comment: Brilliant, thx.

Comment: Hmm... Turns out this only does the wheel button, not the scrolling action.

Comment: Ah. I'm sorry about that - I thought it could do both. I'm unaware of any other solutions. Hopefully the IntelliPoint software is still useful to you for something though at least.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Autohotkey](http://autohotkey.com) for this. I'm not sure what the window class of PowerPoint is, but you can find that easily with window spy, a tool that comes with AHK, then use this script:

```
#IfWinActive PowerPoint ahk_class INSERT_CLASS_HERE
WheelDown::return
WheelUp::return
#IfWinActive
```

replace `INSERT_CLASS_HERE` with the PowerPoint window class.

Comment: In PowerPoint 2013 the class of a running presentation is `screenClass`. I used it to disable ESC key with `*Escape::return`